# Intellij IDEA: Breakpoint not being hit, and is shown greyed out

Tags: intellij-idea

Running JDK 1.7 on Mac OS X and suddenly breakpoints on my project are not working, and they are appearing greyed out.  They were working earlier today, so not sure what I have done to cause this.  I am using Intellij 13.1.3.  Why would breakpoints stop working like this?

[image: Grey, non-functioning breakpoint in Intellij 13]

Comment: Looks like it's disabled, right click on it and check

Comment: You can post that little edit as an answer, and chose it as the correct on, even if it's your own :)

Comment: Thanks Morfic - posted as answer below :)

Comment: No problem, also if you want the users to get notified when you reply to them, put an @ in front of their name in the response, eg: `Thanks @Morfic...`

Comment: Grey breakpoints aren't even mentioned here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/breakpoints-icons-and-statuses.html

Comment: For me, File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart solve the problem

Comment: I like muting and unmuting all breakpoints in my project at once while debugging. You can achieve that with [Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F10] in default settings.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Oh Gee - I just saw the "Mute Breakpoint" button in the debugger window.  My mistake: picture below for the next person who might be as inattentive as me:

[image: The mute breakpoint button]

Comment: Took me a good half hour before I looked it up and found this page. Now I just feel stupid. Worst thing: cannot recall clicking the button in the first place.

Comment: Not even sure why you would want to be in debug mode and mute break points.

Comment: Idea team should notify the user in a better way about this. How about a tooltip over the grey breakpoing saying "This breakpoint is muted. Unmute by ..."

Comment: I know I pressed the disable breakpoints button. I turned out to be the mute button. I would make this button gray just like the muted on really looks like that way your eye can catch that more easily. Sure now that made this mistake I will likely always know. But consistency in looks allows to match it a bit better to my opinion. At the end of the day - there is a reason why so many of us made this mistake. Stop red square is obvious, Green play button is awesome, this green bug is DeBug. But this one may need to be relooked at

Comment: I am glad I looked it up after spending 10 minutes debugging the cause. would have wasted a good amount of time before realizing.

Comment: There are a lot of people "who might be as inattentive as me". Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @MikeHogan Thanks a lot for this question and answer including screenshot. Was struggling with this for 2 days.. Pooh :(

Comment: @MikeHogan I almost melt my brain trying to find out why my breakpoints stop working sundennly, thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy to do with a touch bar and not realise. The icon on the touch bar is more obvious than the one in the debug panel.