# IntelliJ IDEA: Breakpoint not being hit, and is shown without the tick, just a red dot

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a gradle project, and when I put a breakpoint it is displayed as a red dot, with a tick inside, and it just works fine.

[image: working breakpoint]

The problem is that in some classes (in the same project, not a dependency class), the red dot doesn't have a tick inside, and it doesn't tell why it wouldn't work. And it just doesn't work..:

[image]

What have I tried so far:

- Gradle clean & build
- Rebuild project
- Restart debug
- Invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ
- Update IntelliJ to the latest version (2017.2.5)
- Mute & Unmute breakpoints

This question is similar, but clearly not the same: [Intellij IDEA: Breakpoint not being hit, and is shown greyed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612603/intellij-idea-breakpoint-not-being-hit-and-is-shown-greyed-out)

Comment: I had a similar problem, albeit in Eclipse. The non-ticked ones are ones that can never be reached, when the program is run. May or may not be helpful.

Comment: Further to above: no breakpoints had a tick, until a) I ran the application in debug mode (some were ticked), or when I ran the server in debug mode (the other ones were ticked). I then hit the un-ticked ones (which were ticked when the server was run in debug mode), using something like SoapUI to run the web service I was trying to call.

Comment: You may get some clues by checking the Java Debugger logs, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241125.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with Android Studio 3.3 and it makes me crazy. Did you found the root cause of the problem @Pablo?

Comment: @Ognyan yes, check the answer given by Kedar

Comment: Kedar's answer was not helpful about the root cause...

Comment: @Ognyan well for me it was basically what he said. I was setting a breakpoint to a class that wasnt the correct one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Did some searching through IntelliJ Help PDF:
[Help Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/intellij-idea-help.pdf) pg. 431

Their documentation Describes the checkmark as *"Shown at run-time when the breakpoint is
recognized by the debugger as set on an
executable code line."*

and the regular red dot as *"Shown at design-time or during the debugging
session when the class with such breakpoint is
not yet loaded.
"*

So it would seem that the line you're adding the breaking point to never gets executed. You can try stepping up line by line through the class to make sure the class is not getting hung up somewhere.

Comment: this happens at random times. If I unset it and the re-set it, it has the tick again.

Comment: Probably because the edited code doesn't match the compiled code. If you debug then start editing this will happen.

Comment: seems like in the latest version GoLand 2021.3.3 the breakpoint gets disabled when the IDE thinks the code is not reachable. Good feature to have IMO!

Comment: what you are saying is not entirely right! The code gets executed I can see the Toast message but the break point gets no tick mark and no hit at run time. I usually do one or all of the following to solve: 1-restart my computer and rerun the Studio, 2- Clean and build 3- File>Invalidate catches and restart

Comment: For me it was just a bean creation failure which I had missed from the output

Answer (score 11):

I made a n00b mistake on the IDE. Instead of hitting the debug button, I thought it would work the same as visual studio or eclipse in that I'd have to use the run button, yet when I hit the debug button (That looks like an actual bug) my break-point hit just fine.

Comment: Haha, same. The bug icon makes it work

Answer (score 4):

I get this same issue intermittently from time to time, I always run the latest version of IDEA. The break points are shown as red but without a tick inside them. Even after I rebuild or re-run in debug they do not get a tick, and they do not "work", i.e., the code continues. I resolve by restarting IDEA, then restarting the debugger/debug run config.

Answer (score 4):

The same happened with me on Mac machine. I followed these steps and all worked fine:

1. Stop server.
2. Close all intellij projects.
3. Open only the specific intellij project on which my application needs to run.
4. Start the server in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue and found that my tomcat configuration was not right.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The scope tag had value as "provided". Changed it to compile and it worked fine.

Comment: and where can we find this configuration?

Comment: Tomcat configuration is a part of your project's pom.xml file. Search for tomcat in it and see if it matches the one I have posted above. If it doesn't match replace that with this one and see if it solves your problem. 
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by manually deleting all build-related files (for some reason Rebuild did nothing) by running this command at the project's root folder. Note that it does also remove Intellij's temporary configuration files, that are usually not included in git repositories anyway. Replace MODULE with the subfolder containing the module for the project. If you are building an Android app with Android Studio the main module name is usually `app`.

```sh
rm -rf ./local.properties ./.gradle/ ./.idea/ ./MODULE/build/ ./MODULE/out/
```

Then restart Intellij with the `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` option, wait for the build and indexing to finish, and debugging should start working again.

Answer (score 1):

**Rebuild** solved my problem.

```
clean & rebuild
```

Invalidates caches/restart if necessary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my mac, tried restarting server, machine, invalidate caches and nothing helped. Then, I noticed when the server is started in debug mode, i didnt see this message:
`Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64197', transport: 'socket'` and I realized that there could be some problem with the server as such.

**Solution:**
Created new server using command line "./server create " and then associated this server for run configuration. Now started server in debug mode and I saw above message connected to socket port and I am able to see the tick marks on debug point.

Answer (score 0):

Android app configuration was the problem for me. I had `minifyEnabled true` in `debug` section inside `buildTypes` in `build.gradle` file. I had to change it to `minifyEnabled false`. This change forced me to set `multiDexEnabled true` as it states in this post [Android gives error "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341627/android-gives-error-cannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file/51341735)

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved by just updating the IntelliJ in IntelliJIdea -> Check for updates..

Answer (score 0):

All,

This could be a common bug in the Intellij IDEA debugger instead use the key short cuts
like F8 and F9  etc  during the debug steps for [ step over and run to debug next point etc..] and don't rely on the debug console buttons provided in the ide

Answer (score 0):

For some reason we experienced this when we upgraded from java 11 to 17.  The fix was to use a SpringBoot configuration and not a maven configuration for run/debug.

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue but when we upgraded from Java 8 to 11, like you, debugging with SpringBoot configuration is ok, but with maven doesn't stop in the breakpoints. Have you any news about that?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a port problem, I don't know why but I had to go back to port 8082 which I was using for tomcat.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30989646)

Comment: For me any answer could be useful, but you're right procrastinator, in the same  time still a mysterious problem to fix, btw did you face the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Make a note of the Java version in the run configuration tab (for me its JDK 9 or later)
- Go to File -> Settings -> Search for Java compiler -> set Project Bycode version to the same version that you see in run config.
- Stop and rerun debugging.

[Run config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWe7c.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Here is what I did.
- My code was within an anonymous class where the
  debug point would not get the tick mark.
- I extracted the code to a
  new instance method of the main container class. Then I was able to set
  debug point in the new method.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the execution was not breaking at the breakpoints set in an inner class.

Did the following steps and it worked:

1. From the menu items, `Run` > `View Breakpoints`
2. On the Breakpoints dialog, uncheck and check the box for all breakpoints, named `Java Line Breakpoints`

[image]

3. Click on `Done`

When I came across this issue again, had to do the above steps to get it working.

**IntelliJ IDEA Version Details:**

[image: About IntelliJ Screen]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however, it was limited to one of the projects. Then I compared the two Run/Debug configurations and discovered a parameter called "before run" that was causing the debug indicator to disappear. The problem was resolved by removing that setting.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails projects:

Instead of using a "Grails Run/Debug Configuration" in IntelliJ, right-click `grails-app/init/Application.groovy` (or whatever subpath the file may have) and choose the debug option from there.

In my case, now only this brought back the ticks to my debug points.

A Micronaut Run Configuration was created in my project and I was able to save it via the arrow next the new appearing "Application" entry in the Run Configurations dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the JavaScript Debug, restartet it, but that didn't change something. I then changed to a different browser in my run configurations and suddenly the debugger worked again. But the one breakpoint that I actually wanted to hit still didn't get hit. I had to remove and set the breakpoint again, then it worked (tried that before changing the debug browser, that didn't work, only after changing the debug browser and resetting the breakoint, it worked.)
I changed from Edge to Chrome, and when it happens in Chrome, I change back from Chrome to Edge (it happens 1-2 times per month... :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should laugh or cry! I've spent so much time to figure it out that what's going on, tried all the suggested solutions non of them worked for me!
Turned out I needed click on the debugger link in the debug logs in console and open it!

So basically what I did:

1- **Open the debug logs, click on the link**:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57292/...
```

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfPhv.png))

2- It will open a new debugging tab

3- Re-add the breakpoints, then you'll see the white checkmarks!

4- Done, that's it!

Answer (score -1):

[image: Disable breakpoint button]

As shown in the picture above.
You can check whether the breakpoint is disabled, the disabled breakpoint button will be grayed out there.