# Android gives error "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file"

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, dex

I don't know why but it's impossible to launch my app on my mobile this morning. I get this error message:

> Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a
> main-dex list.
>
> # methods: 68061 > 65536 Message{kind=ERROR, text=Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
>
> # methods: 68061 > 65536, sources=[Unknown source file], tool

I'm really new to Android and I don't understand the problem and what I need to do? And why I get this problem now and not before?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

In root `build.gradle` file do something like:

```
dependencies {

    // ...

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {

        // ...

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

More details here: [Error:Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 72477 > 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249633/errorcannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file-try-supplying-a-main-dex)

Comment: Anyone wonder which `build.gradle` file please update following file `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: An important detail. This error started after updating com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads from version 19.3.0 to version 19.4.0 in the "build.gradle" of my app. My app has two flavors, PRO and FREE. Since the com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads only applys to the FREE version, instead of adding "multiDexEnabled true" in the gradle "defaultConfig", you must add it in the "productFlavors" area in your "build.gradle"

Comment: I have added it without implementation and it worked (!)

Comment: This makes me wonder what we're supposed to do if it wasn't for a site like StackOverflow? Same thing happens when I beat a game using a walkthrough, then start exploring "why didn't I know that", and finding out there really was no way to know.. Is that true here?

Comment: This worked for us.

Answer (score 33):

Running RN 0.62 and this worked for me with successful build.

**Update build.gradle**
[image]

`classpath('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3')`

**Update defaultConfig**

[image]

`multiDexEnabled true`

After those 2 changes, restart the gradle build again.

Comment: Thnaks you but it worked for me only  with multiDexEnabled true.

Comment: Perfect answer. Nothing better than seeing visuals of exactly where things need to be added in.

Answer (score 16):

Multidex is not always the solution to the problem, is true that it will generate more dex files to fit your method count, but be sure to not import more methods that you need because this in long term will make your builds slower than before.

For example, if you just need to use the location library from play services, you have two options

First one is implementing the whole play-services libraries that will come with location

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

These whole libraries could have more than 40.000+ methods (is only an estimative, I don't really know the total count), being close to reaching the 65536 limit methods.

Instead you should be targeting only the libraries you will use instead of the whole bundle of libraries

in this case

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
```

could have just 50 - 100 methods to work with, which will be better at build time than loading a whole bunch of methods from the whole library package that you won't ever use.

this is just a tip to avoid getting

> Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.

### For minSdkVersion above android 5.0 API 20 +

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
> supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
> performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
> classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
> execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
> 5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART.

### If you are targeting lower devices (Android 4.1 API 16) or before Android 5 (API 20)

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
> for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
> classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
> limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
> part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
> the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

You will need to use multidex in this last case

Answer (score 10):

In build.gradle(app) file:
Add the following in the dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And add the following in the defaultConfig,

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Hope you will find the solution.

Answer (score 10):

### Update 2021 Android-X and Android Studio 4.XX:

Adding multiDexEnabled in the default config of your app-level Build.Gradle is enough

**multiDexEnabled true**

See image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Recommended solution for android x

#### why the error

When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture [more information here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

#### solution

just add the multi dex support library to your dependencies in the `buid.gradle (Module: app)` file

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem by following these steps.

**Step 1:** Migrate to AndroidX

Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

**Step 2:** Add this dependency in build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

**Step 3:** In build.gradle's defaultConfig section add:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is comes when you use `deprecated npm` as well as `correct npm` for same purpose

Comment: remove from pakage.json