# Cannot fit requested classes in the main-dex file (# methods: 73539 > 65536)

Tags: android, gradle

Please I have an strange error when trying to build release.
My project is multidex enabled and still gets that error. It seems to be related to the main-dex file, but I can't understand what the problem is.

Also, I have the latest android studio 3.6.2 and latest Gradle build tools. On another note, I have a similar project like this and it builds release successfully.
The main difference between both projects is that this project contains one extra feature:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
```

> Cannot fit requested classes in the main-dex file (# methods: 73539 > 65536)

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'jsonschema2pojo'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {


    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.madarsoft.fitness"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 113
            versionName "5.0.5"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }


        dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            preDexLibraries = false
        }


        bundle {
            language {
                enableSplit = true
            }
            density {
                enableSplit = true
            }
            abi {
                enableSplit = true
            }
        }

        /*sourceSets {

            main {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com.madarsoft.fitness/view']

            }
        }*/
    }

    repositories {

        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

        maven { url 'https://bitbucket.org/tbdsrl/instal-publisher-sdk-releases/raw/master/' }
        maven { url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" }
        maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
            google()
        } // necessary for Android API 26
        maven { url 'https://bitbucket.org/tbdsrl/instal-publisher-sdk-releases/raw/master/' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {


        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
        implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:NiceBottomBar:2.2'
        implementation(name: 'netperf-lib-238-release', ext: 'aar')

        implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:3.0.0'
        implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.0.3'


        implementation 'me.toptas.fancyshowcase:fancyshowcaseview:1.3.0'


        implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.0.0"


        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'

        implementation 'com.github.jinatonic.confetti:confetti:1.1.2'

        implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:2.0.0'

        implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:2.2.0'

        implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC1'

        implementation 'com.scwang.wave:MultiWaveHeader:1.0.0-alpha-1'

        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


        def room_version = "1.1.1"

        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
        kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"


        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
        implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.6'
        implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
        implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
        implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
        implementation 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

        //implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.7'


        implementation 'com.github.hackware1993:MagicIndicator:1.5.0'
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.70'
        implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'


        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'

        // Circle Indicator
        implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
        // ViewModel and LiveData
        implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
        // Lottie
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'


        def work_version = "2.3.4"

        // (Java only)
        implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

        androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"


        api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.16.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'


        api 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.9.3'
        api('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-banner:5.1.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
            exclude module: 'libAvid-mopub' // To exclude AVID
            exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
        }
        // For interstitials
        api('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:5.1.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
            exclude module: 'libAvid-mopub' // To exclude AVID
            exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
        }
        api('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:5.1.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
            exclude module: 'libAvid-mopub' // To exclude AVID
            exclude module: 'moat-mobile-app-kit' // To exclude Moat
        }
        api 'com.instal:instal-publisher-sdk:1.0.26'
        api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        api 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
        api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        api 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:8.1.1'
        api project(':gdpr')

        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.4'
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.4.7'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.4'
        implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'

        api 'com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.4.2.471'
        api 'com.appnext.sdk:banners:2.4.1.471'
        api 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:8.1.0'
        api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'


        api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'


        api(name: 'TremorVideo', ext: 'aar')
        api(name: 'unity-ads', ext: 'aar')


        api(name: 'advads-sdk', ext: 'aar')


        api 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
        api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


        api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
        implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
        api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
        api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
        api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.8.1'


        api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
        //implementation(name: 'DuappsAd-CW-1.2.8.1-release', ext: 'aar')
        implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
        implementation(name: 'ads-librarry-android-release', ext: 'aar')
        api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

        api 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.6.0'
        implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.8.1'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14'
        api 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.3.11'
        api fileTree(include: [' admarvel-android-sdk-core.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:18.0.0'

        //implementation 'com.github.marcinmoskala:ArcSeekBar:0.31'
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
        implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'


    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same error. I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950860/dexoverflowexception-cannot-fit-requested-classes-in-the-main-dex-file) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721083/too-many-classes-in-main-dex-list-main-dex-capacity-exceeded), but not work.