# Ignite CLI (React Native) + Facebook SDK = Android Multidex?

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk

Alright, so really just posting as a sanity check, and making sure I'm not doing my android all wrong. Essentially, it seems needing to use `multiDexEnabled true` is [not best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59532889/4006013), as it means the app is getting "big", aka bloated. But it takes very little to get there with the tools I'm using, which I'll outline below.

TL;DR: Using multidex seems to be bad practice, is there a different solution?

Starting with a vanilla [Ignite CLI](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) [Bowser project](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite-bowser), a template engine for React Native, and adding the [React Native Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) according to the official guide, results in a build error for the android application.

`ignite new TestApp`

`cd TestApp && yarn add react-native-fbsdk && npx react-native link react-native-fbsdk`

Following [Android Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android), make  relevant changes to
`TestApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/testapp/MainApplication.java` and `TestApp/android/settings.gradle`

Then, following the linked Facebook SDK guide ([auth wall](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android)), made the relevant changes to `TestApp/android/app/build.gradle`, `TestApp/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `TestApp/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Then, running `npx react-native run-android`, results in the following build error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

More searches point to a fix of adding `multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig` within the module `build.gradle`, which does fix the error. The issue, is most of those solutions also lead to others pointing out poor library management, importing too much, etc.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is this just the result of using Facebook SDK and Ignite CLI and there's nothing I can do about it? I just worry, as I was hoping to add more than one provider's OAuth to the application, but don't want a bloated application that never loads.

Answer (score -1):

It's not related to libraries used in your project but to the number of methods used.

`When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture` and you have to turn on multidex to be able to support more methods.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I would say what you quoted does refer to libraries used, not just # of used methods. I already stated I've enabled multidex, and am wondering if there is any other solution I'm not seeing