# JPDA doesn't seem to work in IDEA deployed with JBoss

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, remote-debugging, jpda

I have a Java project which is deployed on remote JBoss server that I'm trying to debug using JPDA in IDEA.

The following was added to JBoss config to turn this feature on:

```
"JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

I created a new debug configuration in IDEA for the server and it seems that the port is opened and I'm able to connect:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'here's goes the IP:8787', transport: 'socket'
```

However, when I add breakpoints in the app it doesn't seem to stop executing the code.

There's a REST controller which is I'm absolutely sure should trigger the breakpoint when request is sent to the server. But for some reason that's not the case.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Invalidate Caches/Reset IDEA
2. Make request to server via Postman instead of browser

But with no luck.
The code on the server should match with my local project.

I'm pretty convinced that the problem has to be on my side.

I've only debugged applications deployed with Tomcat, maybe there's something specific about JBoss?

Might be related to [IntelliJ IDEA: Breakpoint not being hit, and is shown without the tick, just a red dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692606/intellij-idea-breakpoint-not-being-hit-and-is-shown-without-the-tick-just-a-r) since there's no ticks and also gradle is used.

In addition, I remember when I debugged a tomcat + maven project with JPDA and added breakpoint, IDEA would evaluate and calculate something for a considerable amount of time but in the current project there's no sign of it.

Comment: Try to attach the debugger using "Remote JVM Debug" run configuration. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html for more information