# Breakpoints not working in Grails run configuration (anymore)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails, breakpoints

After I have re-installed my development machine (and everything on it), IntelliJ (2022.3.2 Ultimate) does not stop at Breakpoints in my Grails 3.3.16 project anymore. It has been working for years before.

I have followed a lot of hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692606/intellij-idea-breakpoint-not-being-hit-and-is-shown-without-the-tick-just-a-r) already, like:

- Checking all Java version configurations are the same (8.0.302)
- Checking the firewall is switched off
- `rm -rf ./.gradle/ ./.idea/`
- Invalidate Caches...
- Gradle Reload
- Rebuild Project
- Checked all debug settings

The current status is:

- The breakpoints stay a plain red circle (without a check tick) after starting the Debug mode
- The console mentions "Running application..." , but not anything about a debug mode or port, on startup
- The "Debugger" frame of IntelliJ keeps showing "Connecting to the target VM..."

`sudo netstat -ntlp` is telling nothing about the port that the Debugger wants to attach to. So it seems like the code is just not provided on the port that the debugger is attaching to (to put in my words).

Does anyone know any more aspects I should check?

Comment: I've noticed there's a limit to how many breakpoints you can have after which intellij starts ignoring them, when this happens I open the all breakpoints dialog (double red dots icon) and delete some/all of them then try again.

Comment: Try to re-create your Run/Debug configuration from scratch. Check if there are any related exceptions in the idea.log file after starting the application in Debug mode. (Help | Slow log in... | open idea.log file | scroll till the end | reproduce the problem | check the logs)

Comment: If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new Attach a project sample, if possible

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make this Grails run configuration work again. But fortuitously, I stumbled across the opportunity to debug the project by a *Gradle* run configuration. This is merely a workaround than a solution, but it works perfectly fine using the same breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click `grails-app/init/Application.groovy` (or whatever subpath the file may have) and the choose the debug option from that menu.

In my case, this created a Micronaut debug configuration. You can save that new configuration: click on the dropdown arrow in the Run Configurations dropdown, that should contain "Application" now, and choose the saving option there.